# WINE giving a black screen on Precise Pangolin

Tags: 12.04, wine, gnome

I'm running Precise Pangolin with GNOME 3.4. Whenever I run a WINE Application there is a chance that the application will show a black screen  and a chance that it might run properly. I haven't found a way to exit the black screen besides rebooting the entire system. Ubuntu seems to be still running properly in the background but I can't access the terminal or anything else. If rhythmbox is open the music keeps playing. I didn't have this problem with the same WINE applications on OpenSUSE 12 or Oneiric Ocelot but back then I was running GNOME 3.2. The applications run smoothly on Windows 7. It's really annoying to reboot the system every time WINE displays a black screen so is I'm wondering, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Which WINE version you currently working on? What exactly do you mean by "there is a chance that the application ... " ,does it mean that only sometimes blank screen happens?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean! Sometimes this issue occurs and sometimes it doesn't. I'm using Wine 1.4. I downloaded it straight from the Software Centre.

Comment: Try upgrading it to 1.5.6 which is currently available on their site. But make sure to completely remove the previous version through terminal before installing the new version.

Comment: The same problem still occurs with Wine 1.5.6. I also tried updating my Nvidia driver

Comment: The issue was fixed after Compiz and the Nvidia driver were updated a few times.

Answer (score 2):

That happens to me too sometimes.

In my case I just close or exit the wine application by pressing **`Alt+F4`**. If that doesn't close wine, try pressing **`CTRL+ALT+F1`** to switch to console mode and kill wine from there.

Comment: I can't switch to the console view, pressing Alt+f4 and CTL+ALT+F1 do nothing at all.